# What's the difference between MOV, MOVZ, MOVN and MOVK in ARMv8 assembly?

Tags: arm, armv8

I was using a disassembler when I came across MOVZ and was a bit confused, since I had only used MOV before.

The ARMv8 ISA manual explains of course all the details, and that MOV is an alias for the other three depending on the context, but maybe someone can provide some rationale here, and give concrete examples to speedup the learning process.

Comment: What's your manual? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/MOVZ.html describes the differences in quite a short way, so I'm kind of confused what you are looking for.

Comment: @domen https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile seems a bit better. But I'm guessing it must be there somewhere.

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. `movz - Move shifted 16-bit immediate to register.` Then: `movn - Move inverse of shifted 16-bit immediate to register.` How much shorter do you want it?

Comment: @domen one could explain the encoding of immediate to new users I think, and show why we need the three encoding types.

Comment: @Close voters: can you explain rationale? There are thousands of assembly questions on SO, so it seems like a well established topic. You should likely open a meta post instead to decide once and for all for all of them instead of close-voting one by one.

Comment: Was not one of the voters, but I think the rationale would be that questions reads like a request to do work (summarise, test maybe) instead of you rather then a genuine specific question.

Comment: @domen OK, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 39):

### MOV

This instruction can take many forms, depending on the value needed to be moved. And it changes if the value is a register or if it is an immediate. If it is in a register, then it produces an `ORR` instruction (`ORR <Xd>, XZR, <Wm>`)*. If it is using the `SP` (Stack Pointer) it produces an `ADD` instruction (`ADD <Xd|XSP>, <Xn|XSP>, #0`)*. If moving an immediate, then it is one of the MOVZ, MOVK or MOVN instructions.

> *These are the 64-bit prototypes.
> `XZR` is the zero register and its value is always zero. The `XZR` and the `SP` share are identified by the same number (31), that is why an `ORR` instruction cannot be used when the `SP` is the destination or an operand. Instead the `ADD` instruction is used.

### MOVZ and MOVK

These two instructions are sometimes used one after the other.
And they are used to move immediate values.
`MOVZ` moves an immediate value (16-bit value) to a register, and all the other bits outside the immediate value are set to Zero. The immediate can be shifted to the left `0`, `16`, `32` or `48`. `MOVK` moves an immediate value but leaves the other bits of the register untouched (the `K` is for keep). For example, let's say you need to move this value `0x7fb7fb1f88` to register `x0`. First, you will move the first 16 bits (bits 0 to 15) with a `MOVZ` instruction, so the rest bits of the register are set to zero. And then you will move the second 16 bits (bits 16 to 31) with a `MOVK` instruction, so the value moved before (the first 16 bits) remains in the register, and you do the same with the other resting bits.

```
      instruction                     value of x0
mov    x0, #0x1f88           |        0x1f88
movk   x0, #0xb7fb, lsl #16  |        0xb7fb1f88
movk   x0, #0x7f, lsl #32    |        0x7fb7fb1f88
```

### MOVN

`MOVN` is usually used for moving bitmasks, here the `N` stands for negated. Let's say you want to move the bitmask `0xffffffff0000ffff` to x0.
Then you will move `0xffff` shifted to the left 16, that will make the value `0x00000000ffff0000`. Negating this values becomes 0xffffffff0000ffff.

Here is an example:

```
      instruction                     value of x0
MOVN x0, 0xFFFF, lsl 16       |       0xffffffff0000ffff
```